# How to implement vue-social-sharing correctly in vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, socialsharing-plugin

I'm trying to use vue-social-sharing, but I get this error "Component is missing template or render function".
this is my main.js file

```
import {library} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import {fas} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import VueSocialShare from 'vue-social-sharing';
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const VueApp = require('./App.vue').default;
  const app = createApp({
    components: { VueApp},
    template: document.querySelector('#app')!.innerHTML,
  });


  library.add(fas);

  app
  .component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
  .component('VueSocialShare', VueSocialShare)
  .mount('#app');
});
```

And on a vue file I'm using it as a normal component `<VueSocialSharing />`

What am I doing wrong and turn it into a functional component?

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you using? [Only the alpha build supports Vue3](https://github.com/nicolasbeauvais/vue-social-sharing#vue-3-support): I suspect that you’re not using that version, hence the error message.

Comment: Hello Terry,
I've installed the plugin via this command ```npm install --save vue-social-sharing@next```

Comment: You should register is like a plugin, not a component. It should be `Vue.use(VueSocialShare)`

Answer (score 4):

For Nuxt@3 users:

create a plugin. ( ~/plugins/socialShare.ts )

```
import VueSocialSharing from "vue-social-sharing";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VueSocialSharing);
});
```

then you could use `<ShareNetwork>` everywhere in your templates to generate your share buttons.

Comment: doesnt work even if you add `'vue-social-sharing/nuxt'` to nuxt config

Comment: @JimOvejera, I confirm it works.I have couple of websites using this. no need to add anything to nuxt config just create the plugin and use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't register it as a component.
All you need is:

```
import VueSocialSharing from 'vue-social-sharing';
const app = createApp(...);
app.use(VueSocialSharing);
```

And in your component, use like this:

```
<ShareNetwork
  network="facebook"
  url="https://news.vuejs.org/issues/180"
  title="Say hi to Vite! A brand new, extremely fast development setup for Vue."
  description="This week, I’d like to introduce you to 'Vite', which means 'Fast'. It’s a brand new development setup created by Evan You."
  quote="The hot reload is so fast it\'s near instant. - Evan You"
  hashtags="vuejs,vite"
>
  Share on Facebook
</ShareNetwork>
```